# Using logical bitwise operators to convert ASCII to binary

Tags: ascii, logical-operators

How could AND, OR, NOT or XOR be used to convert 7-bit ASCII code for a numeric character into a 7-bit pure binary representation of the number?

Answer (score 0):

> code **AND** 1111<sub>2</sub>

You have to take the four lowest significant bits of your ASCII code.

Please note that a single ASCII character can represent only digits from `0` to `9` so 4 output bits are enough to represent the resulting number.

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer.

I would perform a `XOR` operation on the ASCII code with the bitmask `011 0000` (48). The idea is that you minus 48 from the ASCII code to get the actual value of the digit, and `XOR` mimics subtraction.